# Setup File doesnt install the Exe-File

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, exe, setup-project

i recently startet programming my first software, in C# with Microsoft Visual Studios, which is a Note Taking App. When i debug it, everything is fine. The Problem: I added another Project to the Project, which is the Setup Project to create a Setup File. When i go to the Setup Project and add a new Projectoutput and then select Primary Output it should also inculde the Exe-File... But it doesnt. It only includes the .dll, .dll.config and .runtimeconfig.json files. So the result is, when i send a potentially customer the Setup File to install the application, some files get installed except the EXE-File....

Of course my very first step was to google for a solution, but i didnt found anything helpful. Then i tried some steps on my own.
Firstly i tried to delete my Setup-Project and create a new one.
Secondly i read all the compiler warnings in Visual Studios, but all of them were the hint that the loading of symbols got skipped.
Thirdly i got paranoid and searched for the Exe-File in the Main Project, which was there.

Comment: *"It only includes the .dll"*. What DLL? A project can't generate a DLL and an EXE so, if yours generates a DLL, there is no EXE. I think you're going to need to provide some relevant screenshots.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, "_A project can't generate a DLL and an EXE_" That's incorrect. Beginning with .NET Core (due to it starting to go crossplatform), a project generating an executable application does generate an EXE and a DLL (this can be changed by advanced config settings, though). The exe is not containing the IL code anymore as it was with old .NET Framework build, but all the application's IL code is now in its own assmebly DLL.

Comment: @jmcilhinney First of all thank you for taking your time to help me. The DLL is the one of my main project. And thats also a proof that a project can generate a DLL and EXE. Cause my main project includes an EXE and a dll file. I would love to add some screenshots, but i dont know how... Its my first time on stackoverflow.

Comment: What is the name of the setup project template you used? If you look at the [setup-project] tag you'll see there are a few different types, and the answer will depend a lot on which one you're using.

Comment: I think I was thrown by the ".dll.config" and thought it was .NET Framework. I haven't seen such a config file in a .NET Core app. I guess the ".runtimeconfig.json" should have given it away.

Comment: @sbridewell i created a "Setup Wizard". Or do you mean something else by "Setup project template"?

Comment: I also created a "Setup Project" the same thing happens.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this in the end? I am having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your project is .NET Core 3.1 or later versions, you should choose "Publish Items" instead of "Primary Output" when add project output:

[image]
[image]

You can find instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022#workflow-changes-for-net-core-31-and-later-versions)：

> Select Publish Items instead of Primary Output to get the correct output for .NET Core 3.1, .NET 5.0, or .NET 6.0 projects. To bring up this dialog, select Add > Project Output... from the project's context menu.